# Timing Format in Flex "24-hour clock" and "12-hour clock"

Tags: apache-flex

Kindly guide me.

Timing Format in Flex "24-hour clock" and "12-hour clock"

if "24-hour clock" Button is selected, the control should convert times to 24 hour 
clock time.  For example, if 3:45 p.m. is entered, it should be converted to 
15:45.

if "12-hour clock" Button is selected, the control should convert times to 12 hour 
clock time.  For example, if 15:45 p.m. is entered, it should be converted to 
3:45.

Thanks in Advance

Amit pathak

Answer (score 1):

http://www.popamihai.com/2009/07/flex/example-of-using-the-dateformatter-class-in-flex/

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/DateFormatter.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2

Comment: I think he wants a component for entering time.

Comment: there are described DateFormatter for that in first link i have provided, add to this DateField component and its ready-to-go.

Comment: Thanks for the link but all are related to Data Formatting but i need some link in which time formatting handels

Comment: Thanks for the link but all are related to Date Formatting but i need some link in which time formatting handels –

Answer (score 0):

```
list($hh,$mm,$ss) = explode(":",$time);
if($hh>12)
{
  $hh = $hh-12;
  $ampm = 'pm';
}
else
{
  $ampm = 'am';
}
$newcall_time = $hh.":".$mm.$ampm;
```

Comment: Is this even relevant to the question?